# Maximum number of columns for greenplum,can i modify this value？

Tags: orientation, greenplum

There will be more than 2000 columns in the same table, how do I achieve it?

WITH (appendonly=true, orientation=column),I try to use this parameter to create the table,
But it doesn't fulfill my requirement.
Sorry, I don't understand English, and the question made with Google Translate may not be particularly accurate.